# Creating a great .htaccess file that handles shared resources well

Tags: .htaccess, caching, proxy, compression

I am trying to create an ideal .htaccess file that will tick all the boxes for taking advantage of server compression, but only where it makes sense, and caching of resources on public proxies, again where it makes sense. I have been feeling my way through the process and I think I am pretty much there, but I suspect there might be a bit of finessing left to do and I thought I'd invite suggestions. I have my suspicions it's not there yet because of a great tool I have discovered and I have to share that with you to begin with.

[www.pingdom.com](http://www.pingdom.com) has a great suite of website analysis tools, many of which are free to use and personally I think the best is http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/. This shows you the load time of every element of your page, but more importantly, under it's 'Performance Grade' tab it offeres a breakdown of where things could be better. Now I use a number of JQuery resources that are served by Google (and others) and I understand these should exist on many proxy servers. I'm not sure how to say that in my .htaccess file (although I have tried) and sure enough, Pingdom's anaylsis includes the following feedack:

> The following publicly cacheable, compressible resources should have a
>   "Vary: Accept-Encoding" header:
>
> •http://jmar777.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js
>
> •http://kwicks.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v1.5.1/Kwicks/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js

Well I thought I'd done that, but then again, perhaps it's up to the servers that actually serve those resources to set those headers, and maybe there's nothing I can do about it? Is that so? Anyway here is my .htaccess file at the moment. Please note I have the caching set insanely low because I am still just experimenting / learning with it. I will adjust this up before I go live with it.

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/mydomain/public_html
<Files php.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
<filesMatch "\.(js|css|php|htm|html)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>

# 1 HOUR
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|htm|html|)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public"
</filesMatch>

# PHP - NO CACHING WANTED DUE TO USING SESSION COOKIES
<filesMatch "\.(php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private"
</filesMatch>

# STORE BOTH COMPRESSED AND UNCOMPRESSED FILES FOR JS & CSS
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

You can see I am trying to do a 'Vary Accept-Encoding' towards the end of the file but not sure if this is what's needed. How do I tell clients to access JQuery and the like the proxies those files are undoubtedly stored at, and is there anything else I can do to make my .htaccess file deliver faster and my search engine friendly content?

Thank you for your thoughts.

*Edit:*

It seems my questions here were not clear enough so here goes with some clarification:

1) Is the JQuery library, hosted at Google, something whose proxy availability is somehow under the control of my .htaccess settings, because I make remote reference to it in my PHP, and if so, how should I say, in my .htaccess file, 'please cache that library in a proxy for a year or so'?

2) How too should I specify that Google hosted files should be provided compressed and uncompressed via 'Vary Accept-Encoding'? At a guess I'd say both issues were under Googles control and not mine, so to make that absolutely explicit...

3) Is the compression choices and proxification of files like the JQuery library under my control or under (in this case) Googles?

4) Generally, is anything in my .htaccess file expressed in a sub-optimal (long winded) way and how could I shorten/compact it?

5) Is anything in the .htaccess file sequenced in a way that might cause problems - for example I refer to CSS under three separate rules - does the order matter?

*(End of Edit).*

Comment: Not sure why you major on advertising a commercial product.  There are major FLOSS tools out there that do basically the same job such as to google pagespeed extension. IMHO, this article belongs on a blog and not on SO.

Comment: Floss is something you clean your teeth with. Why do you assume everyone else knows as much about computers as you do? Your arrogance is astounding, as you continue to exemplify for marking my question down. I guess you just despise people who haven't been taught as much as you. Then you have the gall to speak of your 'humble' opinion?!! Incidentally I spoke highly of that website because it merits it. Stack Overflow is a 'commercial product' too, or do you think the owners run it as a favour to you? Mentioning great products is no cause for censure.  If you can't answer my question, butt out.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well. Yes, I did mark you down not because of any opinion of you -- how could I form that? But because of my assessment of your post which is not a specific Q, but more an essay on optimising `.htaccess` in early development.  As I said, I feel this sort of thing belongs on a blog. Use IMO if you wish, it's just that IMHO is a more common usage.  Where do you want us to begin to critique?

Comment: Perhaps you could start by working through and incorporating these [Web Performance Best Practices](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html) and reading some of the many Q&A on specific aspects on this site.  I would happy to answer real Qs or clarify anything that you don't understand.

Comment: I read the 'Best practice' document as result of using 'that' site. I understood about 25% of it, which is why I tried asking here. Enumerating the questions one by one chewed up more space than is allowed in this comment section so I have appended an edit to the original question in which I make the questions as specific as I can.

Answer (score -1):

> Is the JQuery library, hosted at Google, something whose proxy availability is somehow under the control of my .htaccess settings, because I make remote reference to it in my PHP, and if so, how should I say, in my .htaccess file, 'please cache that library in a proxy for a year or so'?

This assertion is not correct.  The browser decides to cache or not, to download or not depending on the header exchange for *that* request only.  So if a query response involves requests to multi-site, then your `.htaccess` file(s) only influence how it caches your files.  How it caches Google's is up to Google to decide. So for example, a request to `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js` received the response headers:

```
Age:133810
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000
Date:Fri, 17 Feb 2012 21:52:27 GMT
Expires:Sat, 16 Feb 2013 21:52:27 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 23 Nov 2011 21:10:59 GMT
```

Browsers will normally cache for a year but may decide to revalidate on reuse:

```
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 23 Nov 2011 21:10:59 GMT
```

And in this case **ajax.googleapis.com** will reply with a 301 and the following headers:

```
Age:133976
Date:Fri, 17 Feb 2012 21:52:27 GMT
Expires:Sat, 16 Feb 2013 21:52:27 GMT
```

This short request/response dialogue will typically require ~50 mSec since this content is CDN delivered.

You might wish to rework your other supplemental Qs in this light since some don't apply

Comment: You say in opening "The browser decides to cache or not" which makes me think you are talking about browser caching. I am talking about proxy caching. Unless I have totally misunderstood here I thought that proxy servers exist near/at ISP's that cache content seen by other users, as long as the associated headers tell those proxies to store them and how long for. I wasn't talking about browsers and browser caching.

Comment: I've only used Vanish and Apache TS myself so I don't know about all these products, but in general ISPs do _not_ have any caching layer as a standard part of their infrastructure architecture, so I am interested as where you got that impression. Though large end-user services such as Amazon, Facebook, WP, ... do implement  their own.  Secondly where do you think any proxy gets its caching metadata from? See [MW:Cache strategy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cache_strategy) as slightly dated example.

Comment: [Here](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/User:TerryE/Traffic_Server_Configuration) is how I set up the OpenOffice.org forums caching architecture.

Comment: All major ISP's have massive investment in proxy server infrastructure for all the obvious reasons, most notably in their case to save on the main commodity they sell - bandwidth. If you didn't know that I now understand why you didn't understand the purpose of my questions here. Try reading that Web Performance source you quoted to me, especially page one point one link one " - Optimizing caching — keeping your application's data and logic off the network altogether". It introduces proxy caching and deals with it as an important and entirely separate topic from browser caching, because it is.

Comment: Frank, I do know what they are.  I have set up a couple for systems that I've administered.  But "all major ISPs"? -- none of the shared hosting service providers that I deal with use them.  I come here to help, not to be slagged off and lectured at by newbies.  This is my last exchange with you.

Comment: So you don't deal with the major ISP's. No shame in that. Thank you for your promise by the way. :)